# jQuery horizontal ui scroll not calculating outerWidth in Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, width, horizontal-scrolling

I'm having a problems to make a jQuery horizontal ui scrollbar work in Chrome. It works just fine in FireFox and even IE, but in Chrome I simply can't make it calculate the correct width of my "content" area. The "container" has a 920px fixed width, so no problem with that, but my "content" is, "on this page", exactly 4983px wide but when calculating with outerWidth() and even outerWidth(true), it will return a nonsense value that's a lot smaller than it should be! 
[Here's the link to the page I'm working on](http://sites.publishyours.com.br/silviamecozzi/pt/obra/deserto_das_palmas.php).

And here's the code I have until now. It's a mess because I'm still working and doing some tests...

```
    var container = $('.gallery');
var content = $('.content', container);

var itemsWidth = content.outerWidth(true) - container.width();

var width = 0;
$('figure').each(function() {
    width += $(this).width();
});

console.log('I dont know if I chose width: ' + width);
console.log('Or if I chose itemsWidth: ' + itemsWidth);
console.log('Actually, none of them is working on Chrome/webkit browsers');


$('.slider', container).slider({
    min: 0,
    max: itemsWidth - 20,

    stop: function(event, ui){
        content.animate({ 'margin-left' : ui.value * -1}, 500);
    },

    slide: function(event, ui){
        console.log(ui.value);
        content.css('margin-left',ui.value * -1);

    }
});
```

Notice that I'm trying to calculate the width value in two different ways: itemsWidth (var) and width (var). None of them work. Strange thing is... if you keep refreshing the browser (Chrome), it will eventually grab the correct width of the "content", but it's like once in every 10–15 tries =\

It seems to be a Chrome/Webkit bug, but I have no idea about how to solve that!
Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I found the answer here at StackOverFlow... the problem with my example is that it includes some images and when the code tries to calculate the width of those images, some of them are not loaded yet. That happens because I'm using `document.ready` where I should be waiting for the `window.onload`event. I could solve the problem simply putting all that code inside   

`$(window).load(function() { /** the code here **/

});`

Comment: Just I side note... I'm still learning jQuery but I think it's important that you don't put all your code inside $(window).load, but only those lines of code that really need to wait for the window to be completely loaded.

Comment: Yes, just read my first comment to my own question. Try using $(window).load to make sure that all your images are being loaded before grabbing the container size. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Hay thanks,  I finally fixed it using another logic.. Thanks again for your help..